# creating two separate persistent stores with RestKit 0.2x

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, restkit-0.20

My project design requires me to create two completely separate persistent stores with two different `RKObjectManagers` with two different `baseURLs` :

manager 1 : will deal with store1.sqlite

manager 2: will deal with store2.sqlite

so, from what I know, I have to create:

1) 2 separate data models: model 1 & model 2

2) 2 separate managed object contexts: context 1 & context 2

3) 1 `persistentStoreCoordinator`

I previously used to setup `RestKit 0.2x` to work with core data (1 store) like this:

```
  NSError *error = nil;    
NSURL *modelURL1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"store1" ofType:@"momd"]];
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel1 = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL1] mutableCopy];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore1 = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel1];
[managedObjectStore1 createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Store1.sqlite"];
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
  if (error) {
NSLog(@"unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
abort();
 }
[managedObjectStore1 createManagedObjectContexts];
manager1.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore1 ;

managedObjectStore1.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore1.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
```

where manager1 is an `RKObjectManager`

My question are:

1) what are the changes should I make to this piece of code to correctly setup 2 completely separate persistent stores ?

2) how can I access the desired context that relates to (store1 for example), I usually use `managedObjectStore1.mainQueueManagedObjectContext]` ?

thank you in advance.

p.s. at `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I have to wipe off all of store 2 data by simply deleting the sqlite file with `NSFileManager` and creating a new clean one, someone may ask why then to persist data ? because using in-memory `NSObjects` would kill the iPhone memory, in my case there are couple of thousands of records to work with.

Comment: Why do you need two completely separate RestKit/CoreData stacks? Isn't it enough to have just two persistent stores?

Answer (score 1):

You won't have one persistent store coordinator, you'll have two. Just copy your code and have 2 stores of all of the details, name them sensibly and access the MOC via the appropriate managedObjectStore as you currently do. The only mildly complex thing is how you access the managedObjectStore because you can't use the RestKit provided default storage now. You should use your own singleton to store your contexts and provide public methods on the singleton.

Comment: is it ok too to have the managedObjectStore as a property of the AppDelegate so I can access it throughout the app? And it's not reasonable to have to coordinators, as i know, the coordinator coordinates between persistent stores.

Comment: You can use the app delegate, but that isn't what it's for. Lots of people do it but it's bad practice. You must have 2 different coordinators as you have 2 different code data models.